# MySql group and sum a field that came from those two or more subquery

Tags: mysql

I have two queries . First QUery

```
SELECT sum(pre.manhour) as manhour
from repair_estimate re

left join repair_detail_pre pre
ON pre.repair_estimate_id = re.id

WHERE re.id  = 3426
+---------+
| manhour |
+---------+
|    NULL |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

THe second query like this :

```
SELECT SUM(first.manhour) as manhour
from repair_estimate re

left join repair_detail_first_additional first
ON first.repair_estimate_id = re.id

WHERE re.id  = 3426

+--------------------+
| manhour            |
+--------------------+
|               1.25 |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

How to group the field manhour and SUM this manhour field came from those two subquery.

Because the first query give null adn the second query is 1.25, then sum is 1,25.

The expected result is

```
+--------------------+
| manhour            |
+--------------------+
|               1.25 |
+--------------------+
```

Please advise

Comment: Table structure, values in it and what's the expected result pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a select union for get to total result

```
  select sum(manhour) as total 
  from (
        SELECT sum(pre.manhour) as manhour
        from repair_estimate re
        left join repair_detail_pre pre
        ON pre.repair_estimate_id = re.id
        WHERE re.id  = 3426
        union all 
        SELECT SUM(first.manhour) 
        from repair_estimate re
        left join repair_detail_first_additional first
        ON first.repair_estimate_id = re.id
        WHERE re.id  = 3426
    ) t
```